# Page Load animation - Remove white flash

Tags: refresh

I have a simple website that is running on a raspberry Pi chriminium in kiosk mode.

The page has two parts;

Page-1.php and Page2.php

Each page has a redirect to the other with a meta tag refresh so it rotates.

I want to remove the white flash that shows between page loads because it really ruins the look of the page.

Can someone suggest a way?  I tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=10.0)">
```

to the headers but the white flash is still there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out with Jquery:

```
function toggle_contents() {
    $('#page1').toggle("slow", "linear");
    $('#page2').toggle("slow", "linear");
    setTimeout(function(){toggle_contents()}, 3000)
}
toggle_contents();

<div id="container">
    <div id="page1">This is page 1 contents.</div>
    <div id="page2" style="display:none;">This is page 2 contents.</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/1/